# How to automate twilio outgoing call testing

Tags: testing, twilio, ivr, twilio-twiml

Looking to add Twilio to one of the project.  Managed to setup outgoing calls with   But how can I automate the testing of these outgoing call scripts ?  or testing the simple IVR that I have setup.

Comment: Using the test credentials lets you test your app without charging your account. More details here -> https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials

Comment: using test credentials does not execute TwiML.  I need to create tests that will initiate an outgoing call to my Twilio phone number, answer the call and enter some pin number and navigate the phone tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio customer Simply Business wrote up an in depth series of blog posts describing how they implemented integration testing for their Twilio based code. I recommend you read through the posts for all the insights:

1. [Part 1: Why testing Twilio integration is hard in our scenario](http://www.simplybusiness.co.uk/about-us/tech/2016/06/continuous-integration-for-twilio/)
2. [Automating tests in your local machine](http://www.simplybusiness.co.uk/about-us/tech/2016/06/continuous-integration-for-twilio-part-2/)
3. [Improving tests to make them deployable to CI environment](http://www.simplybusiness.co.uk/about-us/tech/2016/06/continuous-integration-for-twilio-part-3/)

Comment: Thanks philnash, we ended up getting a third party vendor to help us to perform the testing.